# Geth: how to unlock an account via json rpc

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I am running geth and have my api calls all setup but some are useless as I can't  sendtransaction without first unlocking the related account. The unlock needs to be over the wire as the caller is not on the same machine and may call to different instances of geth on different machines (backups).